# Como obtener resultado de comando openssl en archivo .txt

Tags: php, cmd

alguien sabe como obtener el resultado del siguiente comando: **openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in file.pem** en un archivo .txt. El comando funciona bien cuando lo ejecuto tanto en consola como en la funcion exec de php, lo que no se es como obtener su resultado en un archivo .txt. De antemano gracias, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: A que consola te refieres (cmd, bash, powershell, ...)?

Comment: A la consolo cmd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estás en Windows simplemente puedes obtenerlo en consola redireccionando la salida estándar hacia tu archivo de la sgte manera

```
C:\> openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in file.pem > archivo.txt
```

Comment: Creo que también funcionaría en shell sin problemas

Comment: Mi conocimiento sobre otras consolas es escaso. Gracias!

Comment: Si recuerdo bien `>` sobreescribe, y `>>` añade al final. Por eso lo que propones funcionaría en los dos

Comment: Listo funciono Carlos Muñoz, muchas gracias a ambos.

Answer (score 1):

En la [documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) se especifica que la función `exec()` puede tener de uno a tres parámetros:

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

Seguramente ahora lo estás llamando sólo con uno (el comando), pero te interesaría pasarle un segundo parámetro (output). Este segundo parámetro devuelve un array con la salida del comando (línea a línea).

De la documentación enlazada arriba (traducción mía):

> **output**
>
> Si el argumento output está presente, entonces el array especificado se llenará con cada línea de salida del comando. Los espacios en blanco al final, así como \n, no se incluyen en este array. Nota que si el array contiene elementos, exec() añadirá al final del array. Si no quieres que la función añada elementos al array, llama a unset() en el array antes de pasarlo a exec().

Entonces, sólo tienes que atravesar el segundo parámetro para ver el resultado de la operación realizada con `exec()` y guardarlo en un fichero.

---

Si lo quieres hacer sin necesidad de PHP, y puedes añadir algo al final del comando, podrías hacer algo del tipo:

```
$miComando .= " > fichero.txt";
```

Esto hara que al final de tu comando se añada la cadena " > fichero.txt" que en cmd y shell escribirá el resultado en un fichero txt por ti.

Comment: Correcto, gracias Alvaro Montoro.

Answer (score 0):

si el comando devuelve un código de retorno, este se almacena en la variable `errorlevel`:

```
C:\>openssl

"openssl" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.`

C:\>@echo %errorlevel%
9009
```

Answer (score 0):

tambien hay la opcion de usar los controles de ejecucion de linea de comandos:

**Si ha dado codigo de retorno 0 se ejecutara lo que haya a continuación del &&**

`C:\>openssl&&@echo    ha ido bien`

o

**Si queremos controlar cuando hay error pondremos doble pipe y entonces se ejecutara lo que haya a continuación del ||**

`C:\>openssl||@echo    ha dado error`